# Translating a Dict of List creation from Python to C#

Tags: c#, python, list, dictionary

I am porting code for a gaming project from Python to C#. Right now I'm having trouble translating a specific piece of code, where the game checks if two space ships are friendly or hostile to each other. Factions are identified via integers. Lists of hostile or friendly faction numbers are used.

The functions for checking hostility or friendlyness are (Python):

```
def is_hostile_faction(ownF, oppF):
    hostile_factions = { 1:[5], 2:[4,5], 3:[5], 4:[2,5], 5:[1,2,3,4], 6:[5], 7:[8,9,10], 8:[5,7,9,10], 9:[7,8,10], 10:[7,8,9]}
    if oppF in hostile_factions[ownF]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

and

```
def is_allied_faction(ownF, oppF):
    allied_factions = { 1:[1,2], 2:[1,2,3], 3:[3], 4:[4], 5:[5], 6:[1,2,3,6], 7:[7], 8:[8], 9:[9], 10:[10] }    
    if oppF in allied_factions[ownF]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

respectively. So far, so easy. How would I recreate the same functions in C# without writing ugly code like:

```
List<int> faction1hostiles = new List<int> {5};
List<int> faction2hostiles = new List<int> {4,5};
// etc
Dictionary<int,List<int>> hostileFactions = new Dictionary<int,List<int>();
hostileFactions.Add(faction1hostiles);
hostileFactions.Add(faction2hostiles);
// etc

public void isHostile(int ownF, int oppF) {
    if (hostileFactions[ownF].Contains(oppF)) {
        return true; }
    else { return false; }
}

// same for friendly factions
```

Former code is Python (Panda3D framework), target code is C# (Unity3D framework). Considering the simplicity of the Python code, where data structures are created on-the-fly, there must be a equally simple solution for C#?

Comment: Trying to *translate* code is generally a terrible idea - a solution that suits one language doesn't always suit another. It is best simply to reimplemented in the other language.

Comment: Completely agree with @Lattyware

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do something like that:

```
Dictionary<int,int[]> hostileFactions = new Dictionary<int,int[]>(){
    {1,new[]{5}}, {2,new[]{4,5}}
};

public void isHostile(int ownF, int oppF) {
    return hostileFactions[ownF].Contains(oppF)
}
```

Comment: Yes, something to that degree works. Thanks. I didn't think one could use the new statement "in-line" as done here. I thought one has to tie it to some type-declared variable, and then add this do a reference collection.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you call "ugly code." You could write something like this:

```
var allies = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>{
    {1, new List<int>{1,2}},
    {2, new List<int>{1,2,3}},
    //...
};
```

Or you could keep track of specific hostilities and alliances like this:

```
var alliances = new[]{
    new {a=1,b=1},
    new {a=1,b=2},
    new {a=2,b=1},
    new {a=2,b=2},
    new {a=2,b=3},
    //...
};

var allies = alliances.ToLookup(e => e.a, e => e.b);
```

Or, if you're never going to want an actual list of allies for a given team, and instead you just want to quickly discover whether two teams have an alliance, you could create a set of allied team pairs, like so:

```
private struct TeamPair
{
    private int _team1;
    private int _team2;
    public TeamPair(int team1, int team2)
    {
        _team1 = team1;
        _team2 = team2;
    }
}

ISet<TeamPair> alliances = new HashSet<TeamPair>(
    new[]{
        new {a=1,b=1},
        new {a=1,b=2},
        new {a=2,b=1},
        new {a=2,b=2},
        new {a=2,b=3},
        // ...
    }.Select(e => new TeamPair(e.a, e.b)));


public bool isAllied(int ownF, int oppF) {
    return alliances.Contains(new TeamPair(ownF, oppF));
}
```

I'm sure you could come up with other more concise syntaxes using arrays of arrays, if you really wanted to.

But you may want to consider storing alliance mappings in outside of your code: perhaps an XML or CSV file, or relational database, and then using your code to read that data into a data structure. It feels to me like you're coupling data too heavily with your code.

As @Lattyware mentioned, doing a rewrite gives you a unique opportunity to think of a better way to write your program for the new language: direct translation is rarely the best way to go. Even the original authors probably wouldn't write the game the same way if they had a chance to do it again today.

Comment: Thanks for your code, I will take a closer look later. Yes, I know am coupling too much data with my code as it is. When enough data accumulates, I will externalize the data into XML files, like the existing stuff. Thanks.